# I want to save integer or double value in file ?? I have done to put string by this method

Tags: c#-3.0

string example="Example";

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\WriteText.txt", text);

string output = system.Io.file.Readalltext(@"C:/example.txt");

console.write("output"+output);

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i save integer or double value in file by console ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using System.IO;   //to access the StreamWriter and StreamReader Class.

//to write item to the file

```
string myPath = @"C:/example.txt"; //this is where you put the text.
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myPath);
sw.Write("write something");
sw.Close();
```

//to read the item in the file

```
string myPath = @"C:/example.txt"; //this is where you read the text.
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myPath);
string item = sr.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(item);
sr.Close();
```